# Raise event TreeViewItem.MouseDoubleClickEvent

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having problems with rising event on `TreeViewItem`. I always get this exception

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs' to type
>   'System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs'

There is my code behind the exception.

```
private void LibraryTree_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        if (LibraryTree.SelectedItem == null) { return; }
        TreeViewItem tvi = (TreeViewItem)LibraryTree.SelectedItem;
        tvi.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(TreeViewItem.MouseDoubleClickEvent));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MouseDoubleClickEvent expects MouseButtonEventArgs so raise event like this:

```
tvi.RaiseEvent(new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0, MouseButton.Left)
                           { RoutedEvent = TreeViewItem.MouseDoubleClickEvent });
```